# Determine convergence and limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to determine whether each of the sequences converges, and if so, to what limit.

$$\begin{align} 1. \quad \quad & a_n=\frac{n^{2}}{n+1}-\frac{n^{2}+1}{n}\\
2. \quad \quad & a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}
\end{align}$$

For the first one, I tried to use ratio test, but it's not working. For the second, I tried to multiply it by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ and then devided it. But I'm stuck again and don't know which test should I use to determine its convergence.

Answer (score 1):

For the first sequence, note that

$$\begin{align}
a_n & = \frac{n^2}{n+1} - \frac{n^2+1}{n}\\
& = \frac{n^3-n^3-n-n^2-1}{n^2+n}\\
& = \frac{-n^2-n-1}{n^2+n}.
\end{align}$$

And taking the limit you obtain

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = -1 \quad (\in \mathbb{R})$$

so it converges.

For the second sequence, as you said, multiply the by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ and you will obtain

$$\begin{align}
a_n & = (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}\\
& = \frac{(\sqrt{n+1})^2-(\sqrt{n})^2}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}\\
& = \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit you get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 \quad (\in \mathbb{R})$$

so it converges too.

Comment: The second one converges to $0$, not to $+\infty$. Notice that the denominator $\to \infty$, so one over that is $0$.

Comment: @talbi oh you are right, it was a distraction. Thank you very much for correcting me :)

Comment: @talbi I already corrected the mistake. Once again thank you, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is equivalent to

$$\frac{-n^2-n-1}{n(n+1)}$$

for the second one your way is right, when multiply by

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

you should obtain $1$ for the numerator.